# caldera form wordpress-dynamically populating dropdown list options

Tags: wordpress, dropdown, auto-populating

I need to populate a dropdown list options in a form named "order" with the entries of another form  "agent" . The name of the field to be populated is 'Agent Name', slug:"agent_name". The entries are of field "Client Name" [slug:'client_name']  from form "agent". I am using caldera forms for both the forms.

[Order Form][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vm0B.png

[Agent Form][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTQ72.png

Comment: Show your effort. Post your code.

Comment: @HarshWardhan  added pics of both the forms.